# The Hausdorff ordered pair definition

Tags: set-theory, math-history

I have found on the internet several versions of the formal definition of ordered pair, presented by Felix Hausdorff.

For example:

(a,b) = { {a, 1} , {b, 2} }

(a,b) = { {a, O}, {b,{O}} }     (O is indicating the empty set.)

I would like to know what Hausdorff's definition was really and in what work it is possible to find it. 
I ask for help.

Comment: The second one, I think, is due to Norbert Wiener and not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 4):

[Felix Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Hausdorff), [Grundzüge der Mengenlehre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundz%C3%BCge_der_Mengenlehre) (1914).

See [page 32](https://books.google.it/books?id=Q20_fm7prAYC&pg=PA32):

> $\{ \{ a, 1 \}, \{ b,2 \} \}$.

---

For [Norbert Wiener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norbert_Wiener)'s contribution, equivalent in modern terms to:

> $\{ \{ \{ a \}, \emptyset \}, \{ \{ b \} \} \}$,

see: Norbert Wiener, *A simplification of the logic of relations* (1914), into: Jean van Heijenoort (editor), [From Frege to Gödel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA225), Harvard U.P. (1967), page 224-27.